# Difference between iPhone SDK 3.x and 4.x

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.2

- what is the difference between
  iPhone    SDK 3.x and iPhone 4.x ?
- what is the new features in iPhone ?
- How to feel a iPhone programmer the
  iPhone SDK 4.x    feature. ?

**Thanks & regards.**

Answer (score 4):

See the "Whats new in iOS 4" documentation from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW1